# Android:PopupWindow.showAtLocation()

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me the detail explanation of the param "**parent**" in the function `PopupWindow.showAtLocation(View **parent**,int w,int h);`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Android window manager makes sure that the popup window is shown above the activity that showed it. In order for the window manager to do this, it needs to know the window of the activity in question. Since a View is inside a window, it knows what window the activity is in if it knows of a View inside the activity window.

With the *parent* parameter, you say "I want the popup window above the activity in the window that the View *parent* is in".

Comment: 多谢，but are you sure about that？：->

Comment: As sure as I can be based on inspection of the Android platform source code.

Comment: Not only *activity*, this relates also to *dialog* window.

Answer (score 5):

From the javadoc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) it states that:

> parent - a parent view to get the getWindowToken() token from

A quick look at the javadoc for [getWindowToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowToken%28%29) gives this explanation

> public IBinder getWindowToken ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Retrieve a unique token identifying the window this
>   view is attached to.
>
> Return the window's token for use in WindowManager.LayoutParams.token.

What this means is that the 'parent' view is any view attached to the current window in order for the PopupWindow to get a reference to the window. It's not used for positioning or anything else - in fact with a little work you could create a dummy view that just passes the relevant IBinder object from the getWindowToken() method.