# Android: Set size and location of quick action at Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, dialog

I want to use ***QuickAction dialog*** in my learning App, but I don't know how to change the size of the dialog. Now, the dialog is close to phone border, but I want to left blank between borders or reduce the width.
Thanks~
[image]

call `setRootViewId(R.layout.notify_quick_action);` at constructor.

```
public void setRootViewId(int id) {
        mRootView   = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(id, null);
        mTrack      = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tracks);
        mArrowDown  = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
        mArrowUp    = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_up);
        mRootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        setContentView(mRootView);
    }
```

call show() at setOnItemClickListener()

```
public void show (View anchor) {
        preShow();

        int[] location = new int[2];
        mDidAction = false;

        anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + anchor.getWidth(), location[1] 
                            + anchor.getHeight());
        mRootView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int rootWidth       = mRootView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int rootHeight      = mRootView.getMeasuredHeight();

        int screenWidth     = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        int xPos            = (screenWidth - rootWidth) / 2;
        int yPos            = anchorRect.top - rootHeight;

        boolean onTop       = true;

        if (rootHeight > anchor.getTop()) {
            yPos    = anchorRect.bottom;
            onTop   = false;
        }

        showArrow(((onTop) ? R.id.arrow_down : R.id.arrow_up), anchorRect.centerX()+180);

        setAnimationStyle(screenWidth, anchorRect.centerX(), onTop);
        Log.d("-------", "xPos="+xPos+";yPos="+yPos+";rootWidth="+rootWidth+";rootHeight="+rootHeight+";screenWidth="+screenWidth);
        mWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, yPos);

        if (mAnimateTrack) mTrack.startAnimation(mTrackAnim);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps help you:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926689/androidpopupwindow-showatlocation
AND
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440334/how-do-gravity-values-effect-popupwindow-showatlocation-in-android AND http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.widget.PopupWindow/showAtLocation

Answer (score 0):

Just use custom `PopupWindow`. Yeah, here link:
https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/